# Makemigrations after splitting models not detecting changes

Tags: python, django

I am developing a django app in virtual environment. Django version 1.9.7.

I splitted the `models.py` into multiple files and kept them in a folder with `__init__.py` file.

```
|-- Models
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- PersonModel.py
|   `-- VehicleModel.py
```

Content of **init**.py file is -

```
from .VehicleModel import *
from .PersonModel import *
```

Inside VehicleModel.py file, I created a model.

```
from django.db import models

class Vehicle(models.Model):
        regNo = models.charField(max_length=16, null = False, blank = False, primary_key = True )
        chassisNo = models.charField(max_length=64)
        engineNo = models.charField(max_length=64)
        manufacturer = models.charField(max_length=128)
        product = models.charField(max_length=128)
```

Now when I am running python `manage.py makemigrations MyAppName` it says `No changes detected in app 'MyAppName'`

I did initial migrations and default tables are created in DB.

Also I don't have anything in migrations folder except init file.

Comment: you have forgotten to delete the old models.pyc

Comment: There is not a single .pyc file. I deleted them bcz I was getting some errors.
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete

Comment: @User42 Ya, I just googled and it says the `python manage.py sql APP_Name` has been discontinued. Let me look for an alternate. And hence I must also take down my answer.

Comment: I found `sqlmigrate`, but I don't think it really solves your purpose. See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455706/equivalent-of-sqlall-in-django-1-9 The last comment says that there is no equivalent for `manage.py sql` now

Comment: Thanks. sqlmigrate expects migration name and I don't have anything in migrations folder. updated the same in question.

Comment: Yea. Plus according the docs also, it doesn't really serves the purpose you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just import all models into 'models.py' as the django look up for models in models.py for migrating a schema.